# Nextjs plus nextauth cannot configure jwt

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth, twitch-api

I am trying to setup JWT with NextAuth and it's just being a pain, reading through posts on GitHub, and researching is returning no help. I have a feeling it's some error happening when NextAuth attempts to decode the JWT payload, I am just trying to return a string of numbers that are returned from Twitch upon signin, I need this to use in a API call to Twitch.

I am new to JWT and NextAuth so I am no pro!

github repo for entire project https://github.com/MatWebsites/next-auth-example-main

#### Any help would be huge!

```
// console errors
unhandledRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next-auth.session-token')
-
error - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
-
TypeError: getCurves is not a function
-
```

nextjs error page [image: error]

```js
//[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Providers from "next-auth/providers"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Twitch({
      clientId: process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    Providers.Spotify({
      clientId: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,

  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },

  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#jwt
  jwt: {
    // A secret to use for key generation (you should set this explicitly)
     secret: process.env.SECRET,
    // Set to true to use encryption (default: false)
    // encryption: true,
    // You can define your own encode/decode functions for signing and encryption
    // if you want to override the default behaviour.
    // encode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {},
    // decode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {},
  },
  callbacks: {
     async signIn(user, account, profile) { return true },
    // async redirect(url, baseUrl) { return baseUrl },
     async session(session, user) { return session },
     async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) { 
       token.accessToken = account.access_token;
       return token 
      }
  },
  theme: 'light',

  debug: true,
})
```

```js
//test.js - trying to decode and use the data inside the web token
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
const secret = process.env.SECRET

const test =  (req, res) => {
    const token = getToken({req, secret});
    return (
        <div>
            <a>{token.sub}</a> // Should show the users id returned from Twitch
        </div>
    )
}

export default test
```

Answer (score 1):

`getToken` returns  a promise. You have to `await` for it before doing any operation on it.

```js
const test = async  (req, res) => {
    const token = await getToken({req, secret});
    return (
        <div>
            <a>{token.sub}</a> // Should show the users id returned from Twitch
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Adding this still results in this error error - 
`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: In `jwt` callback , try adding  accessToken conditionally, l`if (account){ token.accessToken  = account.access_token`

Comment: `account`  argument is only available on first time sign-in , so try adding a condition.